# Android Push Notification Sound is missing (Not Working ) background and foreground on android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-notifications, notification-channel

I have implementing FCM for push notification.
I am calling this OnMessageReceived Method but the sound is not played when the app is in the foreground and background

here is my code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static  String ChannelID = "";
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1041;
public static boolean IsDriverBusy = false;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private NotificationChannel mChannel;
private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    System.out.println("notificationIntentIs   0000000000000123545 onMessageReceived  " + IsDriverBusy);

    String mTime = getDate(remoteMessage.getSentTime());
    String RiderLOcation = remoteMessage.getData().get("RiderLocation");
    String RiderID = remoteMessage.getData().get("RiderID");
    String Dlat = remoteMessage.getData().get("Dlat");
    String DLong = remoteMessage.getData().get("DLong");
    String Plat = remoteMessage.getData().get("Plat");
    String Plong = remoteMessage.getData().get("Plong");
    String RiderName = remoteMessage.getData().get("RiderName");
    String RiderRating = remoteMessage.getData().get("RiderRating");
    String MainBody = "RiderID:" + RiderID + ";RiderName:" + RiderName + ";RiderLocation:"
            + RiderLOcation + ";PLat:" + Plat + ";PLong:" + Plong + ";DLat:" + Dlat + ";DLong:" + DLong + ";RiderRating:" + RiderRating;
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("LoginDetail", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.getString("id", "").equals("")) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);

    } else {
        if (!IsDriverBusy) {
            sendNotification(MainBody);
            PreferenceHandler.writeString(this, PreferenceHandler.RIDE_DETAIL, MainBody);
        }
    }

}

private String getDate(long time) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time * 1000L);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", cal).toString();
    return date;
}

@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("bookingId", messageBody);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    startActivity(intent);
    ChannelID=getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.raw.windchime);
    long[] VIBRATE_PATTERN = {0, 500};

    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setVibrate(VIBRATE_PATTERN)
            .setPriority(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notificationData))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        AudioAttributes mAudioAttributes=new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelID, "Qwykr_Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(VIBRATE_PATTERN);
        mChannel.setImportance(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mChannel.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI,mAudioAttributes);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    clearNotification(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}

public void clearNotification(int ID) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {

        }
    };
    Runnable doDisplayError = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            notificationManager.cancel(ID);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(doDisplayError, 3000);

}
```

}

and I'm using Xiaomi Redmi 7 pro.I'm checking the phone setting app notification channel the only vibration is enabled not a sound and another option is enabled.
How can set a channel like Whatsapp and telegram application?
How can I enable all the fields of the screenshot like Sound, Floating Notification, LockScreen Notifications?
Here is my app Channel screenshot:

[image]

Please Help me out to solve the problem.
Thanks in andvance

Comment: Hi! Have you solved the problem? I have the same one but still no answer was found...

Comment: @SvetlanaRozhkova Try this link....https://stackoverflow.com/a/61909624/8348768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working for me

First You can uninstall your app then try the channel code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = CommonUtill.random();
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)

                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(messageBody).setBigContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {


        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();

        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                getString(R.string.app_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        mChannel.setDescription("desc");
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setSound(sound, attributes); // This is IMPORTANT


        if (notificationManager != null)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

    }
    notificationManager.notify(943/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: The most important part of your answer is the first line:
"Uninstall the app and then try the channel code."

I have done everything for the sound and its working on the background, not in the foreground. Re-installing the app is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

What type of FCM you are sending? Is it Notification message or Data message? If it is Notification message `OnMessageReceived` will not be called when app is in the background. The notification will be taken care of by the ststem tray. 
If you want to run `OnMessageReceived` while in background use FCM Data message.

EG:

**Notification message:**

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

**Data message:**

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

More about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Comment: in both cases(background and foreground), I received the  notification with data but sound and vibration is not working

Comment: @MohitLakhanpal Have you find any solution here?

Comment: @MehulGohil  Not yet, I faced this on some of the phones

Comment: @MohitLakhanpal Okay